# Django 1.11 don't include login.app

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my login app, when I configure the logout in urls.py the traceback tell me the next:

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/CursoProDjango/eventus/eventus/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    url(r'', include('myapps.users.urls', namespace="users_app")),
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/CursoProDjango/eventus/myapps/users/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views 
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/CursoProDjango/eventus/myapps/users/views.py", line 11
    if user_register.is_valid():
                               ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

My urls.py is :

```
from django.conf.urls import  url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('myapps.events.urls', namespace="events_app")),
    url(r'', include('myapps.users.urls', namespace="users_app")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my users/urls.py is :

```
from django.conf.urls import  url
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.UserLogin, name="login"),
    url(r'^salir/$', views.LogOut, name = 'logout'),
]
```

my users/views.py is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from .models import User
# Create your views here.

def UserLogin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'register_form' in request.POST:
            user_register = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if user_register.is_valid():
                User.objects.create_user(
                    username = user_register.cleaned_data['username'], 
                    email = user_register.cleaned_data['email'], 
                    password = user_register.cleaned_data['password'])
                LogIn(request, user_register.cleaned_data['username'],
                    user_register.cleaned_data['password'])
                return redirect('/')
        if 'login_form' in request.POST:
            login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if login_form.is_valid():
                LogIn(request, login_form.cleaned_data['username'],
                    login_form.cleaned_data['password'])
                return redirect('/')

    else:
        user_register = UserRegisterForm()
        login_form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', 
        {'user_register' : user_register,
        'login_form' : login_form

        })

def LogOut(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

before I configure this logout all working fine, but now I don't know what is the problem, because I usually no working with Django this is my first app in Django and I learn very slow, could you help me?

Comment: Sorry Alasdair, but I don't see what is the solution in the question that you marked like duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example), need to specify only `view` for url mapping.

Comment: I change it, but this is not the solution, because when I had only `url(r'^login/$', 'myapps.users.views.userlogin', name="login"),' in my users/urls.py it was working fine. but when I added the logout url it don't work.

Comment: I create a file functions.py with function LogIn and now is working fine.